# How to activate virtual environment

Tags: python, django, frameworks, virtualenv

I installed Django not knowing I was to create a virtual environment before installing it.(I don't know if I am making sense) but now I cant activate my virtual environment? is there something that I can do to rectify this

Comment: It is not a problem. You installed Django globally, that's it, and you can easily uninstall it. It shouldn't cause any problem with the creation/activation of virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

if Django is installed in local environment you can uninstall it using pip command as : `$ pip uninstall <package-name>`.

and if you want to create a virtual environment and install Django in it for that you can use `pipenv`  as `pipenv install django==<version>` but for that you need to install `pipenv` which you can install using `pip` as `pip install pipenv`

Answer (score 0):

**Virtual Environment Cheats:**

Create a new virtual environment [env] is the name of your environment

```sh
virtualenv env
```

Activate virtual environment:

```sh
source env/bin/activate
```

Deactivate virtual environment:

```sh
deactivate
```

If you want to redo your virtual environment, you can always delete the environment folder and recreate a new environment